# Redundancy and inheritance?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, redundancy

I have 2 different classes: Product and Cart.
In the Product class, I have a method that displays our product information in a table.

The other class: Cart, also needs the same method as the one below. 
Is there any way possible to reuse the code without copying the entire thing.**

I thought about inheritance, but not sure if it makes any sense.

Thank you in advance

```
    constructor(name, location, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.price = price;

    }
// The following method should somehow be in the other class. 

    displayShoppingCart() {
        var orderedProductsTblBody = document.getElementById("orderedProductsTblBody");


        while (orderedProductsTblBody.rows.length > 0) {
            orderedProductsTblBody.deleteRow(0);
        }

        cartTotalPrice = 0;

        for (var Product in shoppingCart) {

            var row = orderedProductsTblBody.insertRow();

            var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
            var cellLocation = row.insertCell(1);
            var cellPrice = row.insertCell(2);

            cellPrice.align = "right";

            cellName.innerHTML = shoppingCart[Product].name;
            cellLocation.innerHTML = shoppingCart[Product].location;
            cellPrice.innerHTML = shoppingCart[Product].price;

            cartTotalPrice += shoppingCart[Product].price;
            document.getElementById("cartTotal").innerHTML = cartTotalPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jonathan, i don't understand quite well what are you trying to reuse. I do agree to favor composition over inheritance, and you should isolate any common code into a common abstraction (for start a function is fine). I do not see any hierarchical relation between a Cart and  a Product, i do see a composition that a cart aggregates several products (without existential dependence, i mean, a product can exists by hiw own without beign contained in a cart). Looking at your code you are facing UI presentations concerns that tends to mix things with your models and makes harder to see relations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have declared our classes somewhat similar to the following:

```
class Product {
  ...

  getProductInfo() {
    // Here we create the markup we need to display one product nicely
    // We will return it as a string instead of injecting into the DOM
    // The benefit of doing it this way is that the caller may need to 
    // transform the markup in some way (say, the Cart wants to add some
    // extra wrapper around it)
    ...
  }

  // Here the "eltContainer" is the DOM element where we want the product displayed - 
  // can be a table cell, div or any other container of your choice
  displayProduct(eltContainer) {
    const markup = this.getProductInfo();
    eltContainer.innerHtml = markup;
  }
}

class ShoppingCart {
  constructor() {
    this.products = [];
  }

  ...

  displayCart() {
     // Here we prepare the table, clear up the rows etc.
     ...
     for (var product in this.products) {
       const productRow = ... // Create a table row
       const infoCell = ...   // Create the cell that will hold our product info
       product.displayProduct(infoCell);
     }
  }
}
...
```

then we simply reuse the markup generated by each Product and do not need to duplicate or inject the code.

Hope that helps!